# Programming logic/ API experience help?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I need to create a list which will all be programmed in the java code and not XML as the items within the list require processing.  The left side will have a string and the right side will have a numerical value for each row.  This is somewhat like a listView only slightly different as there are two variables for each row one on the right and one on the left.  I need to be able to define and add rows freely in the code.  How do I go about in programming this type of list into my application.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: U mean u want to add a string variable and numeric variable in every item right...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the List3 Example (Cursor (Phones) Example in the API Demos) for an example of how to display columns of different types in a list view.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List3.html